# How to send an encrypted php values using php GET method

Tags: php, html, encryption, get, md5

I have written a php code to send a value from one page to another page using GET method. Is that any other way to encrypt and send the values using GET method?
this is my code:

```
<a href='sample.php?phone=00000000'>click</a>
```

my next page will be like

```
$_GET['phone']
```

Comment: if $_GET is the only option for you, try function URL encode and decode to encrypt and decrypt the value

Comment: is this keep change or fixed `phone=00000000` ??

Answer (score 2):

Try `base64_encode` and `base64_decode`. For your problem

```
<?php
$phone = base64_encode('00000000');
?>
<a href='sample.php?phone=<?php echo $phone?>'>click</a>
```

AND
get that variable by

```
$phone = base64_decode($_GET['phone']);
```

Comment: What about using URL encoding with base64_encoded string?